# Ruby on Rails Microsoft Graph Client Specifying Parameters for Calendars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, calendar, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using rails to build an app that uses the Microsoft Graph client to get events in a users calendar. I've read lots of tutorials and documentation on the graph api, and the problem i'm having is finding resources for the actual client itself. All the documentation shows examples for using an http request, such as:

```
GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/calendarview?startDateTime={start_datetime}&endDateTime={end_datetime}
```

But I can't find any resources on how to add parameters like startDateTime and endDateTime to the graph client itself. For example, this is a sample function from the MS tutorial using the graph client to get events:

```
def index
    token = get_access_token
    email = session[:user_email]
    if token
      # If a token is present in the session, get events from the calendar
      callback = Proc.new do |r| 
        r.headers['Authorization'] = "Bearer #{token}"
        r.headers['X-AnchorMailbox'] = email
      end

      graph = MicrosoftGraph.new(base_url: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0',
                                cached_metadata_file: File.join(MicrosoftGraph::CACHED_METADATA_DIRECTORY, 'metadata_v1.0.xml'),
                                &callback)

      @events = graph.me.events.order_by('start/dateTime asc')
    else
      # If no token, redirect to the root url so user
      # can sign in.
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end
```

They get the events from `@events = graph.me.events.order_by('start/dateTime asc')`
Which is almost what I need, but I need the events between a specific date range.

I believe what I actually want is the calendar view (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_calendarview), and to specify a date range, but I can't find any resources that explain how to specify that date range using the client.

I've tried just getting the calendar view from `graph.me.calendar_view` which works fine but returns a huge amount of data, and I want to specify the date ranges to return the events between.

Can anyone tell me how to specify the date range for the client?

Thanks!

Comment: there is a [`#filter`](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-ruby/blob/master/lib/microsoft_graph/collection_association.rb#L99) method. Please be aware apparently one cannot filter and order

Comment: Probably equally as important *"This client library is a release candidate and is still in preview status, please continue to provide feedback as we iterate towards a production supported library."*

Comment: Please read "[ask]". "Or point me to any resources/documentation" is off-topic because you're asking us to find and recommend stuff for you.

Comment: @theTinMan I was really just adding that as an alternative if someone didn't know the specific answer to my question but happened to know of better documentation I could read

Comment: That may be, but it still results in an off-topic request. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310983/128421 might help. I'd recommend removing the last sentence.

Comment: @theTinMan Noted, I've edited my post, thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 2):

No much documentation on that matter indeed, but this should help:

```
@events = graph.me.events.filter("start/dateTime ge '#{start}' and end/dateTime le '#{end}'")
```